# what is keyboard shortcut to "select text between the cursor and the beginning of the document"

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

**For General knowledge:**

Does anyone know the following keyboard shortcuts for windows machine? I learned them long long time back at the beginning of learning and has forgotten all by now.

- How to "select text between the cursor and the beginning of the
  document" ? and,
- How to "select text between the cursor and the end of the document" ?

Helps are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyboard shortcut for the above two would be

```
Shift + Ctrl + Home
```

and

```
Shift + Ctrl + End
```

reference for these and many other shortcuts:

- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_keyboardshortcuts.asp